# How to define a custom task in project/Build.scala in sbt?

Tags: sbt

With the following task declaration in `project/Build.scala`, the `print` task is not recognised when I type in `print` at an SBT console.

```
lazy val print = task { println("print") }
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `TaskKey` for this to work that can be instantiated by using the `taskKey` macro:

```
lazy val printTask = taskKey[Unit]("print")
```

I recommend having a look at the corresponding [documentation about tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#define-the-key).
The documentation says:

> The name of the val is used when referring to the task in Scala code. The string passed to the TaskKey method is used at runtime, such as at the command line

Answer (score 3):

```
taskKey[Unit]("print") := println("print")
```

Then in your SBT console,

```
> print
print
```

---

In more complex code, you'll usually see keys separate from the settings.

```
val printTask = taskKey[Unit]("print")

printTask := println("print")
```